# probabilities and statistics p(n,k)

Tags: probability

if $N=10$, then what values of $K$ will make $C(n,k) = P(n,k)$??

I solved it and my answer was $k=1$, but I'm not sure if there are any other possible values, like zero maybe, any help ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be asking what values of $K$ make $\dfrac{N!}{K! (N-K)!} =\dfrac{N!}{(N-K)!}$.

Assuming $0 \le K \le N$, you need $K!=1$, so $K=0$ or $1$.